# Download API throwing "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)" error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, aurelia

I'm having a problem with an Aurelia project where the downloadFile API is throwing a "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)" error. It seems to be a timeout error, as the API works fine for small files, but files above ~1MB fail - the API is also working for in-office employees and not at-home employees, I assume this is because the at-home employees have slower connections due to the VPN.

I've tried setting the timeout in web.config by adding the following, but it not make a difference (perhaps due to this being an ASP.NET Core application which uses system.webServer rather than system.web?):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
```

Here's the code for the API:

```
[HttpGet("downloadFile/{fileName}")]
        public IActionResult Download(string fileName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                return base.File($"~/{ fileName }", "application/octet-stream", fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
            }
        }
```